# Rails 3.1 - Identifying Records Not In A Join?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I've made a change in my schema and introduced a new many to many relationship. Most records have been amended but I'd like to identify any that are left 'orphaned'.

I'd ideally like to write this as a method in one of my controllers and present in a view as I think it'd be a useful admin tool for future use (even though records going forward should be fine).

If table A is products and table B is suppliers and C is the join table how should I approach this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didnt try it personally but something like below might work. Not sure to be frank :P

To get if any orphan product is there

```
products  = Product.find(:all, :include => :suppliers)
#for each products
# show the Product unless product.suppliers.any?
```

in the same way

```
suppliers  = Supplier.find(:all, :include=>:products)
#for each suppliers
# show the Supplier unless supplier.products.any?
```

You can give a try with this, I will confirm the solution after going back to home :)